# Rails Zendesk API search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, zendesk-api

I am using the Zendesk official API for rails which is here: https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb

When I try this query it keeps coming back with a stack level too deep error for the render json line.

```
def ticket_search
  client = connection
  search_tickets = client.search('type:ticket status:open')
  render(json: search_tickets)
end
```

However, when I try:

```
mycompany.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?query=type:ticket% status:open assignee:none
```

It successfully returns the JSON. Is there a way to see how it is constructing the query or is my formatting wrong? I also tried lots of variantions with and without the quotes, single quotes, double quotes etc

This does not work either:

```
search_tickets = client.search(:query => 'type:ticket status:open')
```

fwiw I can get the find method below working fine but that only returns one ticket, I need all tickets

```
def ticket_get
  ticket_id = params[:id]  
  client = connection
  ticket = client.tickets.find!(id: ticket_id)
  render(json: ticket)
end
```

Comment: Can you show what the api is returning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add fetch to the end of the query.

```
search_tickets = client.search(:query => 'type:ticket status:open').fetch
```